# Alternatives to axWindowsMediaPlayer component?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

Is there an alternative to the axWindowsMediaPlayer component?

I'd be using it from C#.

Comment: what platform? aps? silverlight? wpf? (etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how robust or viable it is, but you could check out:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/mediashow.aspx?msg=3157508

It's using DirectShow - so even if you can't use it directly, you can use it as an example of how to use DirectShow in your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [.Net Interface to VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC). Not sure the state of it or if there is another better version out there.